# Using TypeScript Decorator on Class Methods implemented as Arrow Function

Tags: typescript, decorator, arrow-functions, typescript-decorator

Disclaimer: I have gone through similar questions posted on SO before. They did help me fix some `TypeScript` compiler issues. But I couldn't find a working, complete, code example.

Problem: I want to use a `TypeScript` decorator on some of my class methods. But the problem is, I'm not able to use them IF my methods are implemented as arrow functions. I have modified my code (as at runtime they are considered more as class properties) based on some articles and SO posts, mainly

1. Optional descriptor `descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>`
2. Return as `any`

After that compiler is accepting the decorator and my code is executing without error. But my decorator code is not working. Simplified code below for reference. Any help on getting the code to work would be helpful.

The decorator

```
// Decorator declaration
export function LogPerf(
    message = '',
) {
    return function (
        target: any,
        key: string | symbol,
        descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>,
    ) {
        if (!descriptor) {
            console.log('Logging performance of property...'); // This log doesn't execute at runtime
            return;
        }

        // following log also doesn't work
        const original = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            const timeStartMilli: number = performance.now();

            const result = original.apply(this, args);

            const timeEndMilli: number = performance.now();

            console.log(`Call to ${key.toString()} took ${timeEndMilli - timeStartMilli} ms. Message: ${message}`);

            return result;
        };

        return descriptor as any;
    };
}
```

And a sample usage, which is not working.

NOTE: This works fine when used on normal instance methods.

```
// Decorater use (on class method, implemented as arrow function)
public export SomeClass {

    @LogPerf()
    public myMethod = (
        data: MyData,
    ): Somehting => {
        // Do something with data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is decorators are meant for applying to `prototype` object. If you check the transpiled js, you'll see why it doesn't work.

```
class SomeClass {
    @LogPerf()
    public myMethod = (
        data: MyData,
    ): Somehting => {
        // Do something with data
    }
}

/** transpiled to: */

class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        this.myMethod = (data) => {
            // Do something with data
        };
    }
}

__decorate([
    LogPerf()
], SomeClass.prototype, "myMethod", void 0);
```

See, the decorator is applied to `SomeClass.prototype["myMethod"]`. However, when you define your method as arrow function, it's initialized in constructor and assign to the `this` object.

The workaround would be:

1. define your method as normal function on `prototype` object, then bind `this` when initialized.
2. overload `LogPerf()` signature to accept an alternative usage like following:

```
class SomeClass {
    public myMethod = LogPerf()((
        data: MyData,
    ): Somehting => {
        // Do something with data
    })
}
```

---

Method 1 can be integrated into `@LogPerf` decorator if you prefer. You can ref this piece of code from [`autobind-decorator`](https://unpkg.com/autobind-decorator@2.4.0/lib/cjs/index.js) lib.

```
function boundMethod(target, key, descriptor) {
  var fn = descriptor.value;

  if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError("@boundMethod decorator can only be applied to methods not: ".concat(_typeof(fn)));
  } // In IE11 calling Object.defineProperty has a side-effect of evaluating the
  // getter for the property which is being replaced. This causes infinite
  // recursion and an "Out of stack space" error.


  var definingProperty = false;
  return {
    configurable: true,
    get: function get() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
      if (definingProperty || this === target.prototype || this.hasOwnProperty(key) || typeof fn !== 'function') {
        return fn;
      }

      var boundFn = fn.bind(this);
      definingProperty = true;
      Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
        configurable: true,
        get: function get() {
          return boundFn;
        },
        set: function set(value) {
          fn = value;
          delete this[key];
        }
      });
      definingProperty = false;
      return boundFn;
    },
    set: function set(value) {
      fn = value;
    }
  };
}
```

The implementation part of method 2 is trivial, you just need to handle the case when only one function arg is passed in, I believe you can figure it out.

The tricky part is how to satisfy TypeScript, here's the function signature you need:

```
export function LogPerf(message?: string): {
    <T extends Function>(fn: T): T;
    (target: Object, key: string | symbol, descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any> | undefined): any;
}
export function LogPerf(message = '') {

  // YOUR IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE

}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/PTAEBEFMGMHsCcCGAXBoAmMA2inIJawB2AUJAB4AOCyoAZgK5HQHGgAysA5gAqTx0AFAFtIAZzGIukAPwAuUGOTx8RLgEoFAbxKg9oADwAVUBWSQi6MaABiTFoSIA+QXSIKjm0EYDcu-YLIuNLICgDyAEYAVjDIADSgANaQAJ4KSipqoAA+iinCEbBYCZhi0CqUqPDy3imUkOg88LD18MgpUGUVVQaIRClOOaBMmHSqDV59KX4AvmRUNPT2rEQc3HwCIuKS0qAAvKAA5IfqoDp6IKAAmmEAqgBKoACSALI87ACiLx8AckYAgkYnmEfqAAOJhD4AZVAAAkPvcPv54JBkAx4KtGMwVqBBKctHM5iQ4EQlBgYAgUGgDpxePwhOoSJcoHA8PxhmJILi2NAcBJQKJkAALWDoBL4YSULCQUREczoUCIay4ZoAdyW2McjIo1DaoF5SusUNgogAwnzrOd9JQGBEsPhoAKUi9USKFQdMKyqfBBIJ-Pp9OgUIgFFM4v7QJN+vtBlaAxcwOBYIoTa7VFxQKr8MKMMGIzNGRGAAK0jYMiPCZ2u0UAJjxZxI+ZIRKAA)